# How do I test for a command failure in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

We use a program at work called tectia ssh. It's ssh enabled on windows.

Usage is

```
SSHG3 server02 "arp -a"
```

That will run `arp -a` on server02 and give me the results.

Well sometimes the SSH daemon isn't running or it's frozen, so I can't ssh in.
But since that isn't a native command to Windows, I don't know how to test it.

When the connection fails it says failed to establish connection.

But I'm not sure how to manipulate that. I tried doing `$test = sshg3 server05` because right now that machine isn't allowing connections.

I didn't get any console output and when I `write-host $test` I get a null field. It has no object properties either.

I was hoping to do something like

```
if ($test.Text -contains 'failed'){
    write-host -foreground red "Connection failed"
}
```

Comment: `if($test=(SSHG3 server02 "arp -a")){"process $test"}else{"no result"}`

Answer (score 1):

Check `$LASTEXITCODE` for a failure code after invoking the command. Non-zero is normally an error. Sometimes there will be multiple error codes based on how many types of failure there are. Or if you'd prefer something fancier you could use a wrapper function like the VSCode team does.

**Exec.ps1**
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4cd50470733dfaaf9cd3f2ee863cef89fadde4b2/build/azure-pipelines/win32/exec.ps1